# netsh add sslcert with disablelegacytls not working in Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows-server-2019, netsh

So I'm trying to add my SSL certificate via `netsh` with legacy TLS versions disabled but it's always complaining about `The syntax supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct syntax.` although it is definitely written correctly. As soon as I remove the parameter `disablelegacytls=enable` the command succeeds. Has anyone ever gotten this to work?

```
PS C:\Users> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:60066 certhash=$thumbPrint appid=$appId disablelegacytls=enable
The syntax supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct syntax.

Usage: add sslcert hostnameport=<name:port> | ipport=<ipaddr:port> | ccs=<port>
        appid=<GUID>
        [certhash=<string>]
        [certstorename=<string>]
        [verifyclientcertrevocation=enable|disable]
        [verifyrevocationwithcachedclientcertonly=enable|disable]
        [usagecheck=enable|disable]
        [revocationfreshnesstime=<u-int>]
        [urlretrievaltimeout=<u-int>]
        [sslctlidentifier=<string>]
        [sslctlstorename=<string>]
        [dsmapperusage=enable|disable]
        [clientcertnegotiation=enable|disable]
        [reject=enable|disable]
        [disablehttp2=enable|disable]
        [disablequic=enable|disable]
        [disablelegacytls=enable|disable]
        [disabletls12=enable|disable]
        [disabletls13=enable|disable]
        [disableocspstapling=enable|disable]
```

According to the official docs this is how it should work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/disable-legacy-tls#option-2-powershell-available-in-windows-10-version-2004-and-windows-server-version-2004-and-newer

```
PS C:\Users> (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion") | select ProductName, ReleaseId, CurrentMajorVersionNumber, CurrentMinorVersionNumber, CurrentBuildNumber, UBR


ProductName               : Windows Server 2019 Standard
ReleaseId                 : 1809
CurrentMajorVersionNumber : 10
CurrentMinorVersionNumber : 0
CurrentBuildNumber        : 17763
UBR                       : 5458
```